# php insert data using check box with affected_rows = -1

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mariadb

I am a newible and have followed a video tut but i face an error .

link:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0HiIUclMv1k

I have ensured that my database was called "member" and table was called "login" and the column called "group"

```
<?php
//$_SESSION['name'];
session_start();
echo "student";
?>

<form action="" method="POST">

<input type="checkbox" name="group[]" value="group1">group1<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="group[]" value="group2">group2<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="group[]" value="group3">group3<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="group[]" value="group4">group4<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="group[]" value="group5">group5<br>


<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">

</form>

<?php

    if  (isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
        //print_r($_POST);
    $group =implode(',', $_POST['group']);
    $db = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'member');
    $db->query("INSERT INTO login (group)
            VALUES ('$group')
        ");
        echo $db->affected_rows;
```

}

the movie have showed "1" that means no error 
but it printed out -1 but i cannot find any error from my coding.
Thank you for your help :)

## EDIT:

this is my database structure

```
 column:   id      name             user    password     type     email     group
    ------------------------------------------------------------------------
            3948271  chansiumin    csm_1     12345678    student  
            3948272  chantaiman    stm_369   369369369   teacher
```

---

Query Output:

```
INSERT INTO login (group) VALUES ('group1')
```

Comment: echo your query, so we can see, could be missing quotes or something

Comment: @ B-and-P the affected_rows = -1 and has some error, i follow movie until 3:00. I ensure that there is no error b4 3:00

Comment: Do this: `$query = "INSERT INTO login (group) VALUES ('$group')";  
echo $query;  
$db->query($query);`  
so we can see the query itself and NOT the result. You have a syntax error, most likely.

Comment: @ B-and-Pit shows"INSERT INTO login (group) VALUES ('group1')" while i press group1 checkbox

Comment: query looks alright, can you run this query manually from phpmyadmin?

Comment: @ B-and-Pis that means go to phpmyadmin and press SQL and run the query "INSERT INTO login (group) VALUES ('group1')" it said MySQL said: Documentation

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'group) VALUES ('group1')' at line 1

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104978/discussion-between-tommy-and-b-and-p).

Answer (score 0):

`Group` is a reserved word [in MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html) and [MariaDB](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/reserved-words/) and should be encased in backticks in all instances in the query when used as a column name.

```
  $db->query("INSERT INTO login (`group`)
            VALUES ('$group')
        ");
```

This should give you the correct response.